# How to correctly create an ArrayList of ArrayLists?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I am trying to create an ArrayList of ArrayLists.  I want to create 25 ArrayLists and have those ArrayList hold different values.  The goal being to create a sorted dictionary by word length.

My code looks like

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
         list2D.add(list);
    for(int i = 0; i < stringList; i++)
         list2D.get(stringList.get(i).length()).add(stringList.get(i))
```

The problem is that every list contains the same values after it finishes.

I know why the problem is happening.  "list" is an ArrayList, ArrayList's are objects and if you edit an object then everything containing that object will be edited.

To fix the problem I tried

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < stringList.size(); i2++){
            if(stringList.get(i).length() == i)
                list.add(stringList.get(i2));
        }
        list2D.add(list);
    }
```

But when I test my "list2D"

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
         System.out.print(list2D.get(i).size()+" ");
```

I get

> 0 0 0 0 0 58110 0 58110 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

and I have no idea why...

Also it might be relevant to note that stringList contains 58110 values.

Also I don't want to have to make 25 different ArrayLists!

Comment: shouldn't your print the size of list2d? I.e. `System.out.println(list2d.get(i).size()+" ")`

Comment: @Steinar thanks, but that was just a typo here, my actual code was fine.

Comment: What type is `stringList` ?  You've written `for(int i = 0; i < stringList; i++)` and I don't see how this makes sense.

Comment: In your inner for loop, you have stringList.get(i).length(). Is stringList 2-dimensional? What does it contain?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would try the following to do a single pass of the stringList

```
List<List<String>> dict = new ArrayList<>();
for(string s: stringsList) {
    int len = s.length();
    // add new array lists as required, could be any length, assuming << 100
    while(dict.size() <= len) dict.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    // add the string to the right list.
    dict.get(len).add(s);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy. For example, you can create them like this:
http://ideone.com/3NZwWU

```
// just for convenience, initializes arraylist with values
static <T> ArrayList<T> AL(T... values) {
    ArrayList<T> r = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T x : values) {
        r.add(x);
    }
    return r;
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    System.out.println(AL(
        AL(3,2,24,131),
        AL("this", "is", "second", "array")));
    // prints `[[3, 2, 24, 131], [this, is, second, array]]`

}
```

Comment: I don't down vote but can you explain how your answer sorts the words by length.

Comment: Oops. Maybe I've been too lazy and answered just to question that was written in the title. "How to correctly create an ArrayList of ArrayLists?"

Comment: Often the text and the question are related, but sometimes ... ;)

Comment: How to create ArrayLists (in an ArrayList) where each array list has the words of the same length.

Comment: if you don't know number of groups in advance, then it's better to use `Map<Integer, List<String>>` instead. Your question assumes suboptimal implementation.

Comment: Or you could do what I did in my answer.  I am sure a Map is ok as well.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  I found a really easy solution though...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    list2D.add(new ArrayList<String>());
for(int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    list2D.get(stringList.get(i).length()).add(stringList.get(i));
```

Comment: @SargeBorsch what do you mean?

Comment: Try running it with word with length > 25

Comment: None of my 58110 words are more than 25 letters long

Answer (score 0):

//makes an arraylist with 19 arraylist elements

```
  ArrayList<ArrayList> arrList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
  for(int i = 1; i < 20; i++){
     arrList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(5*i+5));
  }
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to add that the size arraylist element is 5 elements longer  each iteration